# JUnit5 - How to get test result in AfterTestExecutionCallback

Tags: java, junit, junit5, junit5-extension-model

I write JUnit5 Extension. But I cannot find way how to obtain test result.

Extension looks like this:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.AfterTestExecutionCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestExtensionContext;

public class TestResultExtension implements AfterTestExecutionCallback {
    @Override
    public void afterTestExecution(TestExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        //How to get test result? SUCCESS/FAILED
    }
}
```

Any hints how to obtain test result?

Comment: What's your use case? With the current snapshot and the upcoming milestone (M4) you can [Plug in your own TestExecutionListener](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#launcher-api-listeners-custom).

Comment: I described my use case here. https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/542

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As other answers point out, [JUnit communicates failed tests with exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42723654/2525313), so an `AfterTestExecutionCallback` can be used [to gleam what happened](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42722571/2525313). Note that this is error prone as extension running later might still fail the test.

Another way to do that is to [register a custom TestExecutionListener](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/583). Both of these approaches are a little roundabout, though. There is an issue that tracks [a specific extension point for reacting to test results](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/542), which would likely be the most straight-forward answer to your question. If you can provide a specific use case, it would be great if you could head over to [#542](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/542) and leave a comment describing it.

Answer (score 8):

This work for me:

```
public class RunnerExtension implements AfterTestExecutionCallback {

    @Override
    public void afterTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        Boolean testResult = context.getExecutionException().isPresent();
        System.out.println(testResult); //false - SUCCESS, true - FAILED
    }
}

@ExtendWith(RunnerExtension.class)
public abstract class Tests {

}
```

Comment: This worked for me although not completely sure how to manage the context of the instance of `ExentTest`

Comment: Doesn't work for me. There are no executionExceptions even though assertions fail

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SummaryGeneratingListener` from `org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners`

It contains `MutableTestExecutionSummary` field, which implements `TestExecutionSummary` interface, and this way you can obtain info about containers, tests, time, failures etc.

You can create custom listener, for example:

1. Create class that extends `SummaryGeneratingListener`

> ```
> public class ResultAnalyzer extends SummaryGeneratingListener {
>     @Override
>     public void testPlanExecutionFinished(TestPlan testPlan) {
>         //This method is invoked after all tests in all containers is finished
>         super.testPlanExecutionFinished(testPlan);
>         analyzeResult();
>     }
>
>     private void analyzeResult() {
>         var summary = getSummary();
>         var failures = summary.getFailures();
>         //Do something
>     }
> }
> ```

2. Register listener by creating file

> src\main\resources\META-INF\services\org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener

and specify your implementation in it

> path.to.class.ResultAnalyzer

3. Enable auto-detection of extensions, set parameter

> -Djunit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled=true

And that's it!

Docs

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0/api/org/junit/platform/launcher/listeners/SummaryGeneratingListener.html

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0/api/org/junit/platform/launcher/listeners/TestExecutionSummary.html

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-automatic

Comment: Can you provide some code? What version of JUnit you are using? It's been two years, maybe API has changed in some way :)

Answer (score 1):

I have only this solution:

```
String testResult = context.getTestException().isPresent() ? "FAILED" : "OK";
```

It seems that it works well. But I am not sure if it will work correctly in all situations.

Comment: Did you try this out for both cases. When test passes and fails? I don't think this is working.

Comment: Yes I did. I tried passing test. And test, which failed on assertion.

Comment: The updated one works for now, though not very sure of its reliability.

Answer (score 1):

Fails in JUnit are propagated with exceptions. There are several exceptions, which indicate various types of errors.

So an exception in [`TestExtensionContext#getTestException()`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0-M1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestExtensionContext.html#getTestException--) indicates an error. The method can't manipulate actual test results, so depending on your use case you might want to implement [`TestExecutionExceptionHandler`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0-M1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestExecutionExceptionHandler.html), which allows you to swallow exceptions, thus changing whether a test succeeded or not.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

To implement a test execution callback and get the test result for logging (or generating a report) you can do the following:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.AfterTestExecutionCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;

public class TestResultExtension implements AfterTestExecutionCallback
{
    @Override
    public void afterTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception
    {
        // check the context for an exception 
        Boolean passed = context.getExecutionException().isEmpty();
        
        // if there isn't, the test passed
        String result = passed ? "PASSED" : "FAILED";

        // now that you have the result, you can do whatever you want 
        System.out.println("Test Result: " + context.getDisplayName() + " " + result);
    }
}
```

And then you just add the TestResultExtension using the @ExtendWith() annotation for your test cases:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

@ExtendWith(TestResultExtension.class)
public class SanityTest
{
    @Test
    public void testSanity()
    {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void testInsanity()
    {
        assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

It's a good idea to extend a base test that includes the extension

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

@ExtendWith(TestResultExtension.class)
public class BaseTest
{}
```

And then you don't need to include the annotation in every test:

```
public class SanityTest extends BaseTest
{ //... }
```

Comment: If you want to access the variables in the test class after success or failure, you can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76050531/5761134