# JUnit5 afterAll callback fires at the end of each test class and not after all tests

Tags: junit5, junit5-extension-model

I have 15 JUnit5 classes with tests. When I run them all from maven, the *afterAll()* is executed 15 times which causes 15 notifications to a Slack Webhook. Is there anything else I need to only send one notification?

```
public class TestResultsExtensionForJUnit5 implements TestWatcher, AfterAllCallback {

    @Override
    public void afterAll(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
          sendResultToWebHook();
    }

    @Override
    public void testDisabled(ExtensionContext context, Optional<String> reason) {
        totalTestDisabled = totalTestDisabled + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void testSuccessful(ExtensionContext context) {
        totalTestPassed = totalTestPassed + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void testAborted(ExtensionContext context, Throwable cause) {
        totalTestAborted = totalTestAborted + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void testFailed(ExtensionContext context, Throwable cause) {
        totalTestFailed = totalTestFailed + 1;
    }
}
```

```
@ExtendWith(TestResultsExtensionForJUnit5.class)
public class Random1Test {}
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to implement and install a `TestExecutionListener` from the JUnit Platform, as it is described in the User Guide at https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-listeners-custom -- override the default `testPlanExecutionFinished​(TestPlan testPlan)` method with your notifying call. Here, *all* tests from *all* engines are finished.

Comment: I managed to use this information which led me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42721422/junit5-how-to-get-test-result-in-aftertestexecutioncallback/42723654.  The answer by Alexander Oreshin is what I followed.