# Junit5 get results from test in @AfterEach

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, automated-tests, junit5

I am trying to get some context of the result of the test run in the `@AfterTest`. I would like to have, at bare minimum, knowledge if it passed or not and ideally also the thrown exception if there is one.

However, every parameter I try seems to not be resolvable and I can't find any documentation on what should be available.

Code:

```java
public class TestClass {
    
    @AfterEach
    public void afterEach(
        TestInfo testInfo, //works, but no report on state of test
        // none of these work
        TestExecutionSummary summary,
        TestExecutionResult result,
        TestFailure fail,
        Optional<Throwable> execOp,
        Throwable exception
    ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

What can I do to get this context?

Comment: You’ll have to write your own Jupiter extension for providing this information; there’s no built-in mechanism for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but you can use either a `TestExecutionListener` or a `TestWatcher` (there are also other ways that you can check in documentation).

An example of TestWatcher can be found here: [TestWatcher in junit5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49037406/testwatcher-in-junit5) and a more detailed explanation here: https://www.baeldung.com/junit-testwatcher.

The following code example was partially taken from [here](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/950bbadc353bdca114befc98cf4a18476352220e/testing-modules/junit-5-advanced/src/test/java/com/baeldung/extensions/testwatcher/TestResultLoggerExtension.java).

```
public class TestResultLoggerExtension implements TestWatcher, AfterAllCallback {

   ...  

    @Override
    public void testSuccessful(ExtensionContext context) {
        System.out.println("Test Successful for test {}: ", context.getDisplayName();
    }

    @Override
    public void testFailed(ExtensionContext context, Throwable cause) {
       System.out.println("Test Failed for test {}, with cause {}", context.getDisplayName(), cause.getMessage());
    }
}
```

You test class would be something like this:

```
@ExtendWith(TestResultLoggerExtension.class)
public class TestClass {
```

You can adapt the logic to your needs.

More References:

- https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-test-result-processing
- https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-listeners-custom

Comment: This appears close to what I am trying to achieve. However, for some of my cleanup I am using reflection to determine what needs to be cleaned up, and it seems that `ExtensionContext.getRequiredTestInstance()`  doesn't return the same object as the actual instance of the class used to test...

Answer (score 0):

After trying, I got the following which worked for me:

1. First define TestBase, which includes two abstract methods, failedAfter and succeededAfter, which will be called on success or failure respectively.

```
public abstract class TestBase {
    protected abstract void failedAfter();

    protected abstract void succeededAfter();

    @RegisterExtension
    AfterTestExecutionCallback afterTestExecutionCallback = new AfterTestExecutionCallback() {
        @Override
        public void afterTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
            Optional<Throwable> exception = context.getExecutionException();
            if (exception.isPresent()) { // has exception
                failedAfter();
            } else {                     // no exception
                succeededAfter();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

2. Define the Test class, write tests, and implement these two abstract methods to clean up resources or report errors.

```
public class Test extends TestBase {
    @Override
    protected void failedAfter() {
        // fail
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeededAfter() {
        // success
    }

    @Test
    public void setAndGet() {
        // do some test
    }
}
```